# QGIS: Fill shapefile vectors with grayscale based on elevation

Tags: qgis, vector, rasterization

I am very new to this and feel like this is probably an easy answer, but after days of searching this forum I still am unsuccessful.

I have shapefile data with elevation and I want to create a raster that is filled in (darker with more elevation)  I have tried several things (points, grids, polygons, etc) but I imagine I am missing a step in there somewhere.  The pictures show the starting shapefile, the raster lines that I have been able to create (the lines are all there, they just dont render great when zoomed at this level), and the concept I am trying to accomplish.

What am I missing?

[image: Shapefile]
[image: Raster]
[image: Goals]

Comment: I don't have time to write an in-depth answer, but I suggest to convert your contour lines to polygons (using the line to polygon tool), then associate a height to each polygon in the attribute table, before rasterizing.
You can also have a look at this question: [Can I create a TIN from contours lines (shp) in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/50159/64955)